# "Continue For" Workaround

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

*Note: Although near the borderline, I believe this question does fall more on the "definitive answer" side of the fence as opposed to the "opinion-based" side.*

I have the following code to set data validation for a range of cells:

```
    For Each Cell In WorkCenterFields

        ' If previous cell is empty, clear data validation and go to next FOR iteration
        If Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
            Cell.Validation.Delete
            GoTo NextCell
        ' If previous cell matches this substring, use this list of values
        ElseIf InStr(1, Cell.Offset(0, -1), "INDENG", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            WorkCenterListFormula = "=Sheet0!B2:B11"
        ' If previous cell contains text but doesn't match the substring, use this list
        Else
            WorkCenterListFormula = "=Sheet0!C2:C9"
        End If

        ' Add the data validation list to the cell    
        With Cell.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=WorkCenterListFormula
        End With

NextCell:
    Next
```

This works fine, and makes logical sense. But I don't like how Excel forces the `NextCell:` tag to the far left. Maybe I just need to deal with it.

The obvious Option 2 is just to duplicate the `Cell.Validation.Add` steps into the `ElseIf` and `Else` statements, but like everyone else I hate duplicating code:

```
    For Each Cell In WorkCenterFields

        ' If previous cell is empty, clear data validation and go to next FOR iteration
        If Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
            Cell.Validation.Delete
        ' If previous cell matches this substring, use this list of values
        ElseIf InStr(1, Cell.Offset(0, -1), "INDENG", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            WorkCenterListFormula = "=Sheet0!B2:B11"
            ' Add the data validation list to the cell    
            With Cell.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=WorkCenterListFormula
            End With
        ' If previous cell contains text but doesn't match the substring, use this list
        Else
            WorkCenterListFormula = "=Sheet0!C2:C9"
            ' Add the data validation list to the cell    
            With Cell.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=WorkCenterListFormula
            End With
        End If

    Next
```

My questions are:

1. Are Option 1 and Option 2 computationally equivalent?
2. Are there any pitfalls in using `GoTo` in this way?
3. Are there any better options for code sequence?

   - (I could start by checking for the substring, then setting data validation, then deleting the validation if previous cell is empty. But that seems like shooting myself in the foot.)

Comment: Using `goto` to emulate missing language constructs is perfectly fine. I also add `' Continue` on the `goto` line to make it clearer.

Comment: My take: 1. yes,  2. No, 3. opinion-based. I have seen some development teams that forbid `goto` but also `break` and `continue`. They ended up having code with too many nesting levels of `if-then-else`, more difficult to track, although theoretically *perfectly structured*. It didnt take long until they abandoned this rule :d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your Option 1 and 2 seem to be doing the same thing (testing should confirm this)
2. I see the `GoTo` construct as a disruption in flow - if (when) it becomes more complex it will be harder to debug
3. You're right - duplicating code never helps, but I'd streamline the code like this

---

```
Dim offsetVal As String

For Each cel In WorkCenterFields

    cel.Validation.Delete

    offsetVal = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value2

    If Len(offsetVal) > 0 Then

        If InStr(1, offsetVal, "INDENG", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            WorkCenterListFormula = "=Sheet0!B2:B11"
        Else
            WorkCenterListFormula = "=Sheet0!C2:C9"
        End If

        cel.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=WorkCenterListFormula

    End If
Next
```

---

- You delete the initial validation regardless of the If branches, so do it once at the start
- Extract the offset value just once (minimize interaction with the Range)
- If the cell is empty

  - Move to the next cell (no processing required)
- Else

  - Determine what validation you need to add
  - Add it and move on

Comment: This is exactly the type of feedback I was looking for. I find the tip about minimizing queries to the Range especially useful, I had not considered that. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: And I guess what I meant by "computationally equivalent" was "are they equally efficient at doing the same thing". I believe so, since either way the  sequence is the same.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. The difference in efficiency is not very noticeable for the first few thousand records; it becomes slower after 10-20 k and hundreds of columns; to improve it at that point, I usually compare duration between options by placing a Timer before and and after each implementation (ex `Dim t as Double: t = Timer`, then `Debug.Print "Duration: " & Timer - t & " seconds"`)